# How to use RSpec regex argument matching on certain types of arguments

Tags: ruby, regex, unit-testing, rspec, rspec-rails

RSpec provides argument regex matchers like the following example:

```
mock_smtp.should_receive(:send_message).with(anything, anything, /@just-testing.com/)
```

which is nice, and allows me to catch arguments that match the regex, which works fine for the example (matching a string, ending in '@just-testing.com').

My problem is that I can't get this to work for arguments of this type:

```
    msgstr = <<END_OF_MESSAGE
From: me <#{from_email}>
To: #{to_name} <#{to_email}>
Subject: #{subject}
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-type: text/html

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">...</html>
END_OF_MESSAGE
```

Nothing within the *msgstr* variable is capturable with the regex.

How can I test for values within the *msgstr* variable?

Comment: Huh? A regex should match multiline text as well!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure what problem you're having, but the following works fine:

```
from_email = to_email = subject = to_name = "foobar@just-testing.com"

msgstr = <<END_OF_MESSAGE
From: me <#{from_email}>
To: #{to_name} <#{to_email}>
Subject: #{subject}
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-type: text/html

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">...</html>
END_OF_MESSAGE

def foo(arg)
end

describe "" do
  it "" do
    expect(self).to receive(:foo).with(/@just-testing.com/)
    foo(msgstr)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the example.  After reworking the problem again, your expect syntax worked for me.  The other way started working as well, so I'm not sure where I was going wrong.  Thanks for the help!